# Protege issue: Object property assertion for a class in ontology

Tags: ontology, protege

if I have the same object property value "val1" for all instances of "class1" in ontology, how can I infer that object property value for that "class1" is "val1"

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this more clear to talk about, say you have `Class1` and the object property `property1`. We further assume for `Class1` the only explicitly specified instances are `c1`, `c2` and `c3`. Further we have that:
`property1(c1, val1)`
`property1(c2, val1)`
`property1(c3, val1)`

Now due to your known `c1...c3` instances being linked via `property1` to `val1`, you want to infer that when `property1(x,y)` where `x` is of type `Class1`, it must follow that `y = val1`.

Due to the open world assumption, the possibility exist that another instance, say `c4`, can exist that is of type `Class1` that is related via `property1` to `val2`. Hence a reasoner will not be able to do this inference.

You could use rules though to do this. With SWRL you can state `Class1(?x)  => property1(?x, ?val1)`. This states whenever you have an instance of `Class1` it is linked to `val1` via `property1`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, what I'm doing: I use my ontology to annotate documents, so when a document has a word equal to some instance name I can return object property value for that instance, but when a word is equal to  class name in the ontology I return it but without any value for the property, I'm thinking to add annotation property on class level, but also I've read that if we define an object property we cannot redefine it as annotation property, they must mutually disjoint.so, would you help in this scenario please